# Hover effect (crossfade image) direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, hover

what I am trying to do is to create a hover effect of crossfading images. So, we have two images: img-2 and img-1, and a text up front, so the layers are [img2]>[img1]>[text]. When I hover the text layer or the front image layer, the two images should crossfade eachother and so the layers now are: [img1]>[img2]>[text]. The transition direction I want to apply is from bottom to top. Can I do it with pure CSS, or should I use JQuery? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.box{
  overflow:   hidden;
  position:   relative;
  background: #780;
  width:  250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.boxBg{
  position:   absolute;
  margin-top: 100%;     /* note this */
  transition: 0.4s;     /* this */
  background: #a44;
  width:  inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.box:hover .boxBg{
  margin-top: 0;        /* and this */
}
.boxText{
  position:   absolute;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  width:  inherit;
  color:  #fff;
  font:   200 20px/220px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
  <div class="boxBg"></div>
  <div class="boxText"><p>Hello World</p></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: please add a little explanation to your code-only answer